# Tools to work with Subversion Verify

Tags: windows, svn, verify

We've got about 10 subversion repositories.  To guard against repository corruption we run a batch file that runs the SVNAdmin Verify command against all of our repositories as a scheduled task each morning.

I'm looking for a tool to parse the output of the  SVNAdmin verify command and alert me if there is a problem.

Has anybody got any recommendations or do i need to roll my own ?

Thanks

D

Comment: What OS is your server running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit code of svnadmin will tell you if there was a problem during the verification.  Exit code of 0 means all ok.  Nonzero means there was a problem.

We do this now with our server (WIN2K3).  I have a batch file that runs "svanadmin verify" and "svnadmin hotcopy" each night.  It checks the exit code of svnadmin after each step.  It also does an "if exist" operation to verify the backups are actually created.

Comment: Yes - this is the easiest way to check if the verify worked or not.  I just log the name of any repositories that have issues and email the log file daily.

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN Server Standard Edition (**free**) comes with [`Test-SvnRepository`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Test-SvnRepository) PowerShell cmdlet that helps you verify all your repositories in batch:

```
Get-SvnRepository | Test-SvnRepository
```

You could also make use of scheduled repository verification jobs that will run according to the schedule you choose.